# Can't get data from database - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I have a very simple and short code more or less directly from a course but it doesnt work. I get an error nobody seemingly had before because I can't find a single webpage where my exact error is mentioned.

I'm just trying to get data from my (sql) database in a controller with Laravel. Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Joke as Joke;


class ContentsController extends Controller
{

public function __construct( Joke $joke )
{
    $this->joke = $joke;
}
//
public function index()
{
    $data = [];
    $data = ['jokes'] = $this->joke->all();


    return view('index', $data);
}
}
```

DB migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateJokesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('jokes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('joke');
        $table->integer('upvotes');
        $table->integer('downvotes');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('jokes');
}
}
```

When I try to run it I get this error: "Assignments can only happen to writable values" and its exactly on the line with 
`$data = ['jokes'] = $this->joke->all();`

I'm totally lost.

Comment: Why don't you assign it like this? `$data = $this->joke->all();`

Comment: Use the public or protected $joke; in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is trying to assign the result of `$this->jokes->all()`, to `['jokes']`, which is not a variable, as well as `$data`, which is:

```
$data = ['jokes'] = $this->joke->all();
```

You can't do that in PHP (Or any programming language as far as I am aware). It's just like trying to do something like `1 = 'this is not number 1';`. PHP is complaining about it.

I get the feeling you've just added an extra `=`, where there shouldn't be and your code should look like this:

```
$data['jokes'] = $this->joke->all();
```

This assigns `$this->joke->all()` to an array item with the key `jokes`, which is probably what you want.

Comment: I knew I was just being an idiot. thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't see that...

Comment: I didn't get the syntax either, but I thought I might missed something from the basics of PHP

Comment: @RikvanToorn No problem, glad it helped!